# NAT traversing issue with video conference using webrtc

Tags: php, webrtc, videochat, rfc5766turnserver

I have use **webrtc** for video conference. I used [this tutorial](http://webrtc-experiment.com/) to learn. In local places it works perfectly, but when I try to connect to other country based location it faces NAT traversing issues that [the same tutorial](http://webrtc-experiment.com) said to solve

I should use TURN server **API**

I tried using [this turn server](http://www.anyfirewall.com) but the problem is that it is  working in My country (India) but when I test it with my Netherlands based friends it stops working.

Comment: do both parties gather adequate ICE candidates? Are both able to hit that turn server?

Comment: i should i highly recommend trying to use third party proprietary service for  webRTC. As you can see Different firwall/network configuration will make your app stop.  Many factor will pops up different times and it will be highly risky approach to configure own webRTC client and setting up TURN or STUN server. Use TokBox's opentok api.  You dont even have to touch any Network Related stuff.  All works out of the box with tokbox's cloud infrastructure.